# Multiple watershed delination with QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, hydrography, catchment-area

I am trying to divide a DTM model in subbasins but I have set specific outlet points for the subbasins, and not to use a thershold.

Is there a tool similar to r.water.outlet but with multiple outlet points that allows to do that on QGIS?